# how does cassandra reacts when a write is being performed in node and node went down

Tags: cassandra, hector

We have 2 node Cassandra cluster. Replication factor is 1 and consistency level is 1. We are not using replication as the data we are inserting is very huge for each record. 
How does Cassandra reacts when a node is down when write is being performed in that node? We are using Hector API from Java client. 
My understanding is that Cassandra will perform the write to other node which is running.

Answer (score 2):

No, using CL.ONE the write would not be performed if the inserted data belongs to the tokenrange of the downed node. The consistency level defines how many replica nodes have to respond to accept the request.

If you want to be able to write, even if the replica node is down, you need to use CL.ANY. ANY will make sure that the coordinator stores a hint for the request. Hints are stored in System.Hints table. After the replica comes back up again, all hints will be processed and sent to the upcoming node.

*Edit*

You will receive the following error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
```

Comment: In other words, the write request would return an error in the situation the OP describes.

Comment: Thanks Zerd and Brandon. Hector API is not throwing any exception, but the log shows warning messages about node down status. When i shutdown the node 2, then Hector API is throwing exception. I am using cassandra 2.0.5 version and hector 1.1 version